# Recommend practice for checking if files where copied using SCP

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, scp

I'm trying to create simple backup script that copies some files to timestamped directory on the remote machine - this part is working quite OK, because I didn't run into issues like e.g network connectivity yet.

I would like to know what is recommended practice for checking if my files were copied correctly.

I was thinking about 2 ways to do this:

- Check file sizes/md5 before copying them and compare them with ones on remote machine
- Always copy one more file that will be copied last (like 1 byte file) and then check if it exists on remote machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with [rsync](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html), if it returns an exit code of 0, all is well. If it's not zero, the exit codes are well documented, so your script could tell you exactly what the problem was.